# Como fazer para que o lineEdit do Qt designer receba um inteiro ou float com Python

Tags: mysql, python

Gostaria de saber como faço para que um lineEdit do Qt designer receba um valor do tipo inteiro ou float e armezene essa valor recebido em uma varíavel, pois, preciso fazer operações matemáticas com ele.

Por padrão, o lineEdit recebe um variável do tipo str.

Eu tenho o seguinte código: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
def chamar_segunda_tela():
    tela_total.show()
    cursor.execute('SELECT SUM(preco) FROM tb_registrados;')
    for t in cursor.fetchall():
        total = t

        tela_total.label_5.setText(f'{total[0]:>7.2f}')
        tela_total.label_6.setText(f'{total[0]:>7.2f}')

        dinheiro_recebido =  tela_total.lineEdit_3.text()
```

Já tentei de tudo converter de todos os jeitos, por exemplo: int(tela-total.linEdit_3.text()). Li a documentação, mas não encontrei nenhum método específico para número inteiros ou flutuantes. Já tentei usar o QdoubleValidator sem sucesso, fiz o seguinte:

```
def chamar_segunda_tela():
    tela_total.show()
    cursor.execute('SELECT SUM(preco) FROM tb_registrados;')
    for t in cursor.fetchall():
        total = t

        tela_total.label_5.setText(f'{total[0]:>7.2f}')
        tela_total.label_6.setText(f'{total[0]:>7.2f}')

        validacao_regra = QDoubleValidator(0.0, 5.0, 2)

        dinheiro_recebido =  tela_total.lineEdit_3.setValidator(validacao_regra)
        dinheiro_lol = tela_total.lineEdit_3.setText(dinheiro_recebido)

        print(dinheiro_recebido, type(dinheiro_recebido))
        print(dinheiro_lol, type(dinheiro_lol))
```

Mas aí ele me retorna None<class: none Type> . Li sobre o InputMask, mas não entendi como implementa-lo. Acho a documentação bem confusa.

Alguém pode me ajudar ??

Comment: explica por favor, vc está numa tela e ao clicar num botão, vc chama a função e nela tem duas etiquetas (label_5 e label_6) e uma linha de inserção de dados (lineEdit_3) O que retorna None refere-se ao "dinheiro_recebido"?

Comment: Exato, e tem mais uma coisa que eu descobri, criei uma interface bem simples, só com um único lineEdit, fiz o código padrão e nesse código funcionou a conversão. Eu fiz assim :

def lixo():
    teste_lixo = int(teste.lineEdit.text())
    teste.lineEdit.setText("")
    print(type(teste_lixo))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
teste = uic.loadUi("lixo.ui")
teste.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lixo)  # Utiliza o enter para enviar o código sem necessidade do pushButtom

teste.show()
app.exec()

Dei esse print para ver se a conversão funcionava e funcionou!

Comment: E eu tenho mais uma função chamada "def funcao_1( ):" nesse mesmo arquivo py, fui tentar fazer uma conversão e também funcionou. Ou seja, por alguma razão que eu não descobri, ele não está permitindo a conversão do LineEdit para o tipo int ou float. É muito estranho!

Comment: só mais uma pergunta: vc já tentou tirar o ```dinheiro_recebido =  tela_total.lineEdit_3.text()``` do loop? seria apenas tirar a indentação

Comment: Já havia tirado sim, Carlos, muito obrigado pela atenção, já consegui resolver o problema. Você acha interessante publicar a solução respondendo a minha própria pergunta? Não sei se o SO vai bloquear isso.

Comment: Publique sim... não tem problema

Answer (score 0):

Galera, resolvi o problema, antes eu utilizava esse código:

```
def chamar_segunda_tela():
    tela_total.show()
    cursor.execute('SELECT SUM(preco) FROM tb_registrados;')
    for t in cursor.fetchall():
        total = t

        tela_total.label_5.setText(f'{total[0]:>7.2f}')
        tela_total.label_6.setText(f'{total[0]:>7.2f}')

        dinheiro_recebido = tela_total.lineEdit.text() # Esse código era o problema, dava erro e não conseguia converter de str para float
```

E eu precisava que o lineEdit fosse do tipo float na verdade, para poder realizar conta e imprimir o troco na tela. E quando eu tentava converter, ele retornava o erro "(<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError("could not convert string to float: ''"), <traceback object at 0x00000227F6FF0500>)"

Tentava converter da seguinte forma:

```
dinheiro_recebido = float(tela_total.lineEdit.text())
```

Vi muitos usuários convertendo assim sem problemas, mas só o meu código dava problemas, depois de quebrar a cabeça, um rapaz me ajudou e a solução encontrada por ela foi criar mais uma função e desse vez funcionou, ele conseguiu realizar a conversão de str para float sem maiores problemas.

```
def chamar_segunda_tela(): # Essa tela exibe o total da compra e o total a pagar (que basicamente são a mesma coisa)
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    tela_total.show()

    cursor.execute(f'SELECT SUM(preco) FROM tb_registrados;')
    for t in cursor.fetchall():
        total = t
        tela_total.label_5.setText(f'{total[0]:>7.2f}')
        tela_total.label_6.setText(f'{total[0]:>7.2f}')
    cursor.close()

def tela_pagamento(): # Essa tela é a mesma que a anterior, apenas foi necessário criar a função de receber o dinheiro e imprimir o troco em uma função separada 
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    dinheiro_recebido = float(tela_total.lineEdit.text()) # Aqui a conversão não deu mais erro.
    tela_total.lineEdit.clear()

    cursor.execute(f'SELECT SUM(preco) FROM tb_registrados;')
    for t in cursor.fetchall():
        total = t
        print(total, type(total), type(total[0]))
        troco = dinheiro_recebido - total[0]

        tela_total.label_7.setText(f'{troco:>7.2f}')
```

Coloquei uma imagem em anexo para visualizar a interface funcionando. Obrigado a todos pela atenção ! [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]